# Select a, min(b) but also want C from that same record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, greatest-n-per-group

```
Select A, min(b) from TableX
group by a
```

This works but I want one more piece of information.  The output will be one row for each A with A and the min(b) for that A.

But I also want C from that row.

I cannot figure out how to do it!

MS SQL Server 2012

"C" is the sysident of the row.

So table has

```
Sysident    ID      Date
1            100       2014-01-01
2            100       2014-01-02
3            200       2014-02-01
4            200       201-002-05
```

etc

I want output of

```
Sysident      id     Date
1             100     2014-01-01
3             200     2014-02-01
```

I can get the ID and min date with a simple Select ID, Min(date) group by ID but don't know how to get the Sysident for each of the rows.

When I write/edit this, my sample table looks like a table but when it displays it is all run together.  I have searched HELP for formatting so it will look like a table but cannot find anything.

The question is very clear (to me).  For every unique A, I want the sysident of the row with the oldest date and what that date is.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Is C another grouping criterion?  Is C always the same for a given A?

Comment: What should C do in what condition ? Plz be more specific

Comment: @afzalex: How to write a good answer?  Did you mean question?  At any rate, this question is fairly clear to any SQL programmer ;)

Comment: @Andomar Okay, sorry for wrong link.(I have deleted previous comment) And I wish the user may understand that he should be more specific when asking question and make his question more clear for others next time. Anyway, if you think it is correct then it is okay.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first `date`, you can use `min`:

```
select  id
,       min(sysident)
,       min(date)
from    YourTable
group by
        id
```

If you want a specific version of `sysident`, say the first ordered by the `date` column, you can use SQL Server's `row_number()`:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over (
                    partition by id
                    order by [date]) as rn
        ,       min([date]) over (partition by id) as min_date
        ,       id
        ,       sysident
        from    YourTable
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   rn = 1 -- Only oldest row per value of id
```

For more answers, check out the [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) tag.